# Is it a bad practice to have very long Mocha test?

Tags: selenium, testing, mocha.js

When doing unit test, each case tends to be short and exclusive. But now I'm writing end-to-end tests with `Selenium`, thus, I have long scenarios which contain several closely related steps, for instance:

1. User register
2. User Login
3. User post an article
4. User edit that article

Should any error is caught I didn't expect other test to continue. So,  seems I should put all of above in just one single `it` block. But of course this will make the block very long, and I have to set a big timeout, expect long finishing time etc.

Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how long that really is? For a webdriver bot with proper wait configuration this should ideally under 10s which is okay. 
There are a couple of tips I would like to suggest though.

**Isolated, repeatable test**
It seems you are already using an interesting patterns of acceptance testing.
In his talk on this year's (2017) Craft Conference, Dave Farley explained the idea of writing tests that can be repeated infinite number of times, as each execution is made in the name of a newly created user.

This an interesting approach to tackle the "db restore" problem, that I see many projects suffer from during CI / CD workflows. It does not have to be restored. It may be rebased to a common state but every test provisions all required elements with a new id. For example first run of the test executes with userid1234 the next will go with userid1235.

Therefore one could argue your approach including registration in your process helps you to isolate your executions. I assume the trade-off is that you need to find out what is your base data (that may be part of that initial database state) and what is added.

The traditional school of thought would be to have tests for registration, login, and features independently (well, naively thinking independently). The trade-off there is that if registration failed, no more tests will work.

Link to video of said talk about acceptance testing:

> http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/102892932

**Page objects**

> So, seems I should put all of above in just one single it block.

While some already consider it outdated, it seems the page object pattern will stay for some time. Your 'it' block should not really be that complicated. In your test you should basically find pure English description of what is going on.

```
    it('should deny access with wrong creds', function () {
    LoginPage.open();
    LoginPage.login('Luo', 'SuperSecretPwd'); // Use better forms of Auth
    LoginPage.submit();
    expect(LoginPage.flash.getText()).to.contain('Hi Luo!');
});
```

The idea is that basically any technical details of how a given page is implemented (table vs. CSS grid, etc.) should be kept hidden in those objects.
Then your test is less prone to errors, and can be understood by mere mortals.

More information on Page Object Pattern:

> http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html
>   https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! Yes, I've already adopted both patterns - newly created user for each test and page object. 
Speaking of total execution time, if it's on my localhost it takes around 18 secs. But if I test it against the test server it takes a lot longer, as it needs to download all the resources.